# How to intregrate Cipher with Config-server-client in Spring?

Tags: spring, encryption, yaml, spring-cloud, spring-properties

I'm trying to introduce Cipher encryption for the properties when using "spring-cloud-config-server" but without the Spring Boot as an application runner.

I have to encrypt the config server credentials so was going to do something like below in my bootstrap.yml but what I've learned is that it won't be decrypted automatically even when I have  JCE installed  on my machine.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://someurl:8888  
      username: user
      password: '{cipher}anencryptedpassword'
```

What would be the easiest way to introduce cipher encryption to the app using 
"spring-cloud-config-server" as a dependency?

Comment: You'll have to explain more since it is built around spring boot

Comment: Well, that's in fact a standard jar file, what I'm doing is I override some native behavior of collecting properties for the standard spring project (written in before Spring Boot era). I took this component to be able to retrieve propeties from remote config server but cannot keep the credentials in a plain text

Comment: I'm still confused. If it's not using spring boot, it's not going to work.